# Mapstruct: how to map multiple fields from DTO to an object in Entity?

Tags: mapstruct

i have this DTO:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DataDTO implements DTO {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5105904799152965475L;

    private Long deviceId;

    private OffsetDateTime generatedOn;

    public Long getDeviceId() {
        return deviceId;
    }

    public void setDeviceId(Long deviceId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }

    public OffsetDateTime getGeneratedOn() {
        return generatedOn;
    }

    public void setGeneratedOn(OffsetDateTime generatedOn) {
        this.generatedOn = generatedOn;
    }
}
```

i have this MongoDB document:

```
@Document(collection = "data")
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class DataDocument {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1772572723546311500L;

    @Id
    private IdByDeviceIdAndGeneratedOn id;

    public DataDocument() {
    }

    public IdByDeviceIdAndGeneratedOn getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(IdByDeviceIdAndGeneratedOn id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and this is the @Id class for MongoDB Document:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class IdByDeviceIdAndGeneratedOn {

    @Id
    private final Long deviceId;

    @Id
    @Field("generated_on")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private final OffsetDateTime generatedOn;

    public IdByDeviceIdAndGeneratedOn(final Long deviceId, final OffsetDateTime         generatedOn) {
        this.deviceId = Objects.requireNonNull(deviceId);
        this.generatedOn = Objects.requireNonNull(generatedOn);
    }

    public Long getDeviceId() {
        return deviceId;
    }

    public OffsetDateTime getGeneratedOn() {
        return generatedOn;
    }
}
```

this is the mapper for this Key class:

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR, componentModel = "spring")
public interface IdByDeviceIdAndGeneratedOnMapper {

    default IdByDeviceIdAndGeneratedOn toId(final Long deviceId, final   OffsetDateTime generatedOn) {
        return new IdByDeviceIdAndGeneratedOn(deviceId, generatedOn);
    }
    default Long getDeviceId(final IdByDeviceIdAndGeneratedOn id) {
        return id.getDeviceId();
    }

    default OffsetDateTime getGeneratedOn(final IdByDeviceIdAndGeneratedOn id) {
        return id.getGeneratedOn();
    }
```

and this is the @Mapper for DataDTO and DataDocument:

```
@Mapper( unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR,
    uses = {IdByDeviceIdAndGeneratedOnMapper.class,
            AccelerometerDocumentMapper.class,
            GpsDocumentMapper.class,
            GsmDocumentMapper.class
})
public interface DataDocumentMapper extends DocumentMapper<DataDTO, DataDocument> {

}
```

this is the generic mapper:

```
/**
 * Contract for a generic dto to entity mapper.
 *
 * @param <DTO> - DTO source type parameter.
 * @param <DOCUMENT> - MongoDB Document destination type parameter.
 */

public interface DocumentMapper<DTO, DOCUMENT> {

DOCUMENT toDocument(DTO dto);

DTO toDto(DOCUMENT document);

}
```

Currently i'm receiving this errors:
for MongoDB Data docment:

> Unmapped target property: "id".

for DTO:

> Unmapped target properties: "deviceId, generatedOn".

How to solve this errors without loosing immutability of Id class?

Comment: Can you share the `DocumentMapper` as well?

Comment: @Filip added DocumentMapper

Comment: See https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-with-constructors

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is to use (using constructors to construct objects) is not yet supported. There is an open issue for it [#73](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/73).

However, you can achieve what you are looking for by using [Object factories](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#object-factories), this is for the `toDocument` mapping, for the `toDto` mapping you can use nested source mappings.

Your mapper would look like:

```
@Mapper(uses = {AccelerometerDocumentMapper.class,
            GpsDocumentMapper.class,
            GsmDocumentMapper.class},
componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR)
public interface DataDocumentMapper extends DocumentMapper<DataDTO, DataDocument> {

    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "dto")
    @Override
    DataDocument toDocument(DataDTO dto);

    @ObjectFactory
    default IdByDeviceIdAndGeneratedOn createId(DataDTO dto) {
        return dto == null ? null : new IdByDeviceIdAndGeneratedOn(dto.getDeviceId(), dto.getGeneratedOn());
    }


    @Mapping(target = "deviceId", source = "id.deviceId")
    @Mapping(target = "generatedOn", source = "id.generatedOn")
    @Override
    DataDTO toDto(DataDocument document);
}
```

NB: You can also make `DataDocumentMapper` abstract class and make the `createId` method protected, in case you don't want to expose it in the interface

Comment: The issue you link to has been closed in 1.4.0

Answer (score 0):

this is solved my problem, but this doesnt look elegant.
Maybe there is more elegant way?

```
@Mapper(uses = {AccelerometerDocumentMapper.class,
            GpsDocumentMapper.class,
            GsmDocumentMapper.class},
imports = {IdByDeviceIdAndGeneratedOn.class},
componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR)
public interface DataDocumentMapper extends DocumentMapper<DataDTO, DataDocument> {

@Override
@Mapping(target = "id", expression = "java( new IdByDeviceIdAndGeneratedOn(dto.getDeviceId(), dto.getGeneratedOn()) )")
DataDocument toDocument(DataDTO dto);

@Override
@Mapping(target = "deviceId",    expression = "java( document.getId().getDeviceId() )")
@Mapping(target = "generatedOn", expression = "java( document.getId().getGeneratedOn() )")
DataDTO toDto(DataDocument document);
}
```